# Row hiding macro slow on ribbon excel but fast on '97

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following sub which is triggered by the change of a certain cell on a worksheet. It hides / unhides rows based on the value in column A (the formula in column A is linked to the changing cell, that's why I need to review what to hide everytime the cell changes). I have this working smoothly and instantly on Excel 97, but it takes quite a few seconds on new versions and I have a hard time figuring out what causes this difference. I had the idea that it is because the macro loops through all the rows at some point, but I just can't see where that is happening. Any advice would be much appreciated!
David

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim i, lastrow

'------------------------setting target--------------------
    If Target.Address(True, True) = Range("futamido").Address Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.PrintCommunication = False
'------------------------unprotect sheet----------------------------------------
        If Worksheets("calculation").ProtectContents = True Then
            Worksheets("calculation").Unprotect ("password")
        End If
'-------------------------review hiding settings------------------------
        lastrow = Worksheets("calculation").Range("a1:a1000").Find("*", Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
        For i = 1 To lastrow
            If Worksheets("calculation").Cells(i, 1) = 1 Then
                Worksheets("calculation").Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Else
                Worksheets("calculation").Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        Next i
'------------------------reprotect sheet if other sheets are protected----------------------------------------
        If Worksheets("start").ProtectContents = True Then
            Worksheets("calculation").Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:= _
            True, Password:="password"
        End If

        Application.PrintCommunication = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you think it is important to disable PrintCommunication?

Comment: I was trying to search around for a solution and found a tip that new excel versions communicate a bit too much with printers, so tried that as well, but as it turned out it did not help at all :)

Comment: Do you have column header labels in row 1? If not, is there any chance of A1 containing a 1 and subsequently should be hidden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pls try to change the 3rd part of your code like this:

```
....
'-------------------------review hiding settings------------------------
  lastrow = Worksheets("calculation").Range("a1:a1000").Find("*", Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
  Dim rngHide As Range, rngShow As Range
  For i = 1 To lastrow
    If Worksheets("calculation").Cells(i, 1) = 1 Then
      If rngShow Is Nothing Then
        Set rngShow = Worksheets("calculation").Rows(i)
      Else
        Set rngShow = Union(rngShow, Worksheets("calculation").Rows(i))
      End If
    Else
      If rngHide Is Nothing Then
        Set rngHide = Worksheets("calculation").Rows(i)
      Else
        Set rngHide = Union(rngHide, Worksheets("calculation").Rows(i))
      End If
    End If
  Next i
  rngShow.EntireRow.Hidden = False
  rngHide.EntireRow.Hidden = True
'------------------------reprotect sheet if other sheets are protected----------------------------------------
....
```

and tell if that speeds up the code :)

also as Jeeped mentioned in an indirect way: comment out the `Application.PrintCommunication` if there is no real need to turn it off

Comment: Thank you for the tip, will try it as soon as I have a chance to do so and will get back with the results :)

Comment: Hi Dirk, I have tried the code you have suggested, but I get the following error on this line: "rngShow = Worksheets("Fizetési_terv").Rows(i)":
"Run-time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set"

Since it is dim'd I don't quite get what the problem is here, I'm not very experienced with these kind of range objects. Do you have any idea?
Thanks,
David

Comment: Oh sorry... you need to "Set" ranges. Apologies... missed that part :(

Comment: I've tried it, unfortunately now the code runs to the following error on "rngShow.Hidden = False": Run-time error 1004: Unable to set the Hidden property of the Range class.

It arrives at this error much faster though, so this might be a good sign :)

Do you have any idea on this? As far as I'm concerned the sheet is not protected when this row is executed which could have resulted in this error. Thanks in advance,
David

Comment: Pls try `rngShow.EntireRow.Hidden = False`... there should be no need for it, but to keep that out of the way...

Comment: It looks like this was the problem, the code is now superfast, thank you so much for all the input!:) David

Comment: Could you please edit your code to reflect this change? so I can mark it as solved :)

Do you have any insights on why my original code was working superfast on Excel '97 and waaaay slower on new versions? I can't really see the reason for it, but really happy with the solution anyways :)

Comment: Not really :( I just assume that "animations" will be the big deal here (fading / rolling... instead of just popping on/off)... but normally this should be covered with `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`... :/